# Missing icons within legend QGIS

Tags: qgis, export, mapping

In QGIS 3.10.6 I'm creating some map and I have encountered some issues. When I'm exporting my map, there isn't the colors icon and the text seems gray (it is supposed to be black in my setting)

I have literally no idea on how to correct this.  I use graduated symbology to color the map and data defined size to set my symbols size.

Here is how the map is exported:
[image: Here is how the map is exported]

And this is a screen of the legend properties window:
[image]